# Como descobrir Url de origem

Tags: php, url, navegação, histórico

Preciso de uma função que me mostre a url de origem do visitante da minha página. Já tentei o `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, mas parece que só funciona quando a origem vem de um link clicado.

Atualmente trabalho com um sistema de afiliados, que envia clientes para meu site através de links criados pelo próprio sistema (Antes de ser direcionado de fato para meu site, o cliente passa pelo servidor do programa de afiliado, pra poder registrar esse cliente e quem foi o afiliado que indicou. Porque no caso de venda feita, o sistema de afiliados, paga as comissões devidas).

Eu estou tirando a minha plataforma desse sistema de afiliados, mas como já tem muitos links de afiliados divulgados pela internet, eu gostaria de aproveitar esses links pra não perder vendas.

Um exemplo de link do sistema de afiliado é o http://edzz.la/LQPZ4?a=656180

Como não vou mais utilizar esse sistema, gostaria que a minha página reconhecesse que o visitante esta vindo desse `link`/`url`. Pra que eu possa saber quem é o afiliado que ta indicando esse visitante.

Comment: Não sei se te serve, mas se a sua intenção é apenas manter a Autoridade do seu link que já tem uma boa colocação pelo o Google por exemplo, vc pode fazer um "Redirecionamento 301" para o novo link. O Google Anaytics tb indica de onde está vindo o seu tráfego de maneira geral. Algumas ferramentas como Alexa tb registram esses Backlinks

Answer (score 2):

Os navegadores só preenchem a informação de *referrer* se o usuário tiver clicado em um link mesmo.

Uma requisição HTTP por si só é uma mensagem extremamente simples e com poucos detalhes. O único campo que poderia automaticamente e nativamente identificar uma origem é o *referrer*. Na ausência dessa informação, seus parceiros devem utilizar uma das seguintes formas para passar informações:

- **Query String:** seus parceiros podem incluir algo no final do link, como: *http://www.foo.bar/blablabla/**?origem=parceiro***
- **Corpo da requisição:** se o acesso ao seu site for via *POST* (acho improvável), eles podem incluir um campo no corpo da requisição.

Se não for possível aos seus parceiros passar esses dados, então sinto muito, mas não há nada que se possa fazer.

Comment: Desculpe @Renan, editei a pergunta pra ficar de melhor entendimento, não fui claro na pergunta original. O visitante da página esta vindo de outro servidor, é um sistema de afiliado que não tenho acesso.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira editei a resposta de acordo.

Answer (score 0):

O uso do Cookie como um repositório de página de referência é muito melhor na maioria dos casos, pois os cookies manterão o referenciador até que o navegador seja fechado (e o manterá mesmo se a guia do navegador estiver fechada), então, caso o usuário deixe a página aberta, digamos antes dos fins de semana, e retornou depois de alguns dias, sua sessão provavelmente será expirada, mas os cookies ainda estarão lá.

Coloque esse código no início de uma página (antes de qualquer saída html, pois os cookies serão definidos corretamente somente antes de qualquer eco / impressão):

```
 if(!isset($_COOKIE['origin_ref']))
 {
  setcookie('origin_ref', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 }
```

Então você pode acessá-lo mais tarde:

```
$var = $_COOKIE['origin_ref'];
```

E, além disso, adicione um escaping por $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ser um vetor de ataque comum na web, ao usar o cookie, você também pode querer usar escaping $_COOKIE['origin_ref'] em cada pedido.

Comment: `O uso do Cookie como um repositório de página de referência é muito melhor...` Mas muita gente hoje em dia não guarda cookies. Por isso que muitos sites hoje em dia colocam aquela barrinha na parte inferior dizendo *"ao navegar aqui, você concorda em habilitar cookies no seu navegador..."*

Comment: Oi @Anderson Desculpe, acho que não fui claro. O sistema de afiliados é em outro servidor, é outro serviço. Um serviço que não vou mais utilizar, mas como já tem alguns links de afiliados divulgados pela internet, eu gostaria de aproveitar esses links pra não perder vendas. Obrigado pela resposta.